# Splitting line into segments of different length with ArcGIS Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, line, splitting, linear-referencing

I have a river network and I have to split each river into transects of different length. The distances where the lines have to be split are in an excel sheet.

For example I have to split
the river 1 at the distance of 200, 400, 1000 m;
the river 2 at the distance of 100, 500, 1300 m;
and so on...

I would like to do it with ArcGIS Desktop (I have standard license not advanced).

After some attempts I could locate the points where I want to cut my line. To do that I treated my lines as routes, I saved my excel sheet as dBASE to use it as event table. Then with the function 'make route events layer' I created a shapefile with the point where I have to cut the lines.
Now the problem is that I should probably use the tool 'split line at point', but I dont have the advanced license.

Is it possible to do it with another tool using a lower level license?

Comment: Could you please edit your question, and add the steps you tried so far?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would say you are almost there with one difference. Don't think of them as cut points think of them as reaches. So add a FROM and TO distance field to your dBase table so it contains data as below:

```
ID,FROM,TO
1,1000,400
2,400,200
3,200,0
```

Then when you run the "make route events layer" tool specify that you are making *linear* events. You can then export the Events to a FeatureClass to make it permanent.

Comment: Ty, I didn't noticed that there was this possibility too.